# How to copy a visidata cell to system clipboard on mac?

Tags: visidata

I tried adding to configuration `~/.visidatarc`

`options.clipboard_copy_cmd = 'pbcopy w'`

but when I copy then with `y` from visidata nothing is copied to system clipboard on mac.

How to copy to system clipboard on mac?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One can use the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> for copying data from visidata (as of version 2.5) to system clipboard on macOS.

In detail:

| Table Action | Shortcut |
| --- | --- |
| Copy single cell (of current row and current column) | <kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> |
| Copy selected cell(s) (of current column) | <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> |
| Copy single row | <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> |
| Copy selected row(s) | <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> |

When copying rows, one has to confirm the format (e.g. `csv` or `tsv`).

There is no need to set up visidata options.

Comment: Note that you have to first press `z` then `Shift + Y` - the `+` here needs to be evaluated before the spaces

Comment: To copy the entire column to clipboard, first select all rows (using `gs`) and then do `g z Shift+Y` to copy all selected rows of the current column.